# How can I determine Assets' internal folder_id for use in the {exp:assets:files} tag?

Tags: assets, file-uploads

The subject says it all, really... Assets apparently uses an internal ID for folders that is different from EE's folder ID. Disregarding the reasoning WHY Assets had to have different folder IDs... how can I see which folder ID Assets uses? The only place I've been able to see it is by inspecting the underlying HTML that makes up the folder list on the left in Assets -> File Manager.

Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 1):

Well, the short answer is "managing files and folders when only way of grouping them is by the files relative path is an absolute nightmare." :)

You should not be using that folder id explicitly, anyway, as folders are subject to change.

You should be using http://docs.pixelandtonic.com/assets/templating/module/folders.html to get the folder ids that you need.

Comment: Subject to change? Of all things I would have thought that the folder's ID - like category IDs - would be the one aspect least likely to change... Anyway, the scenario is a single folder dedicated to a frontpage slideshow, so why is there a need to loop through folders when all I'll ever need for this situation will be the one specific folder?

Comment: What I meant is not for a particular folder to change, but for folders within a folder to change.  

If you're looping through a folder and making an album for each folder in there, each of which could be deleted and changed at any time, that would probably be a good candidate to "folders are subject to change" :)  

Also, you don't have to use folder_id - you can use the "folder" parameter and use the same format you would use for {exp:assets:folders} parent_folder parameter:  
{exp:assets:files folder="{filedir_1}resources/slideshow"} or whatever the path to your folder is :)